# View appears different in designer compared to runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

Below is an image displaying the view in designer.

[Image of View from Designer VS2013](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CF671C3CE6993C84!626&authkey=!AMFkHAqk1MgPmW8&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cpng)

Every thing looks great.

Below is an image displaying the view at runtime.

[Image of View at Runtime Windows 7](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CF671C3CE6993C84!627&authkey=!ALOu_Qj-U4fnuc8&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cpng)

Comment: You're going to need to post some XAML if you expect anyone to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had

```
<!--<Style TargetType="Rectangle">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
</Style>-->
```

in a ResourceDictionary and that was causing the issue with the TextBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

In design mode you have a default debug window height and width defined in the windows Xaml. When running, the program's window size may/may not be the size defaulted to during design. Controls are simply filling up the extra space...

If you can shrink the runtime window till the size in runtime mode appears the same as design, that means you have controls which are actively filling up available spaces. That is either due to attributes on the specific controls or content controls being in other controls (*such as a grid with star verses auto size*) which expands/contracts their length and width.